# What type of pattern is generated by mod(x * y, w)? Is this an interference pattern, a simple fractal or some other class of pattern?

Tags: fractals

I've stumbled across this pattern a number of times when working with shaders. The visuals created are very interesting - similar to Moiré patterns, but more intricate.

I don't fully understand how it works and I'd like to know more about it, but I haven't been able to figure out what it's called. Any information or tidbits about this pattern would be greatly appreciated.

[pattern example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gve8t.png)

[pattern example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOTbP.png)

[pattern example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiCwV.jpg)

When applying a scale factor this pattern exhibits fractal-like properties where each node seems to be a smaller version of a similar pattern (but not infinitely).

[pattern example scaled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIXii.png)

However this animated gif suggests to me that it's an interference pattern of sorts (because you can see the interaction of 2 patterns at 2 different scales)

[animation showing interference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGvmC.gif)

Here's a link to the shader where you can test the input parameters:
https://shaderfrog.com/app/view/2754